# Cant get text to wrap in position on the grid within set area

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get the two separate pieces of text onto the same line on the grid, I want the words to wrap around inside the constraints of the grid (or a css border). At the moment the output is the text is not wrapping. Whats missing?

```
<h2 class="text" class="grid_6">Best cheese I've ever tasted!</h2>
<h2 class="text" class="grid_6">Cannot wait to place our next order!</h2>
```

CSS

```
.text {
    word-wrap:break-word;
    display:inline;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
float:left
```

in your CSS

Answer (score 0):

Like this give `display:inline-block;`

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jQD7W/)**

**CSS**

```
 .text {
        word-wrap:break-word;
        display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that had some effect, but the "best cheese" and "cannot wait" texts appear one after the other where I'm trying to get them to appear side by side. Do I need to add something else?

Comment: Thanks, It seems that its moving it to the line below because of the text font size. When i reduce this to a small font both headings appear on one line. My grids "12" so I thought if I have each H2 text an allocation of "6" there should be enough space for both on one line? Do I need to define the grid size? cheers